# Differentiate the Function: $y=\sqrt{1+xe^{-2x}}$

Tags: calculus

$y=\sqrt{1+xe^{-2x}}$

1) Convert radical into a fractional (rational) exponent

$= (1+xe^{-2x})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

2) Differentiate using Chain rule and product rule

$=\frac{1}{2}(1+xe^{-2x})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot (0+(x\cdot [e^{-2x}]'+(e^{-2x}\cdot [x]')$

$=\frac{1}{2}(1+xe^{-2x})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot (x\cdot e^{-2x}\cdot -2)+(e^{-2x}\cdot 1)$

$=\frac{1}{2}(1+xe^{-2x})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot -2xe^{-2x}+ e^{-2x}$

3) Simplify

$\frac{(-2x + 1)}{2e^{2x}\sqrt{1+xe^{-2x}}}$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Don't forget product rule when differentiating $xe^{-2x}$! Also, you appear to have lost a negative sign.

Comment: Can you take a look and see if my answer is correct now?

Comment: you missed "+"  in fourth line $-2xe^{-2x} +e^{-2x}$

Comment: Corrected. Is my answer correct now'?

Comment: now correct your final answer also use brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\\ y\prime =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } { \left( 1+x{ e }^{ -2x } \right)  }^{ -\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }\left( 0+{ e }^{ -2x }-2x{ e }^{ -2x } \right) =\frac { \left( 1-2x \right)  }{ 2{ e }^{ 2x }\sqrt { \left( 1+x{ e }^{ -2x } \right)  }  } \\ $$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. The mistake is in the second step.

Note that 
$$\begin{align}(1+xe^{-2x})'&=0+(x)'e^{-2x}+x(e^{-2x})'\\&=1\cdot e^{-2x}+x\cdot e^{-2x}\cdot (-2x)'\\&=e^{-2x}+xe^{-2x}\cdot (-2)\\&=e^{-2x}-2xe^{-2x}\end{align}$$

Thus, the correct answer *for the second step* will be
$$y'=\frac 12(1+xe^{-2x})^{-\frac 12}(e^{-2x}-2xe^{-2x}).$$

Comment: Take a look at my answer now. See if my answer and process is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Okay! Can you take a look at my answer now?

Comment: Not correct. The correct answer is $$y'=\frac{-2xe^{-2x}+e^{-2x}}{2\sqrt{1+xe^{-2x}}}.$$ Note that this is not the same as what you wrote $$y'=-\frac{xe^{-2x}+e^{-2x}}{\sqrt{1+xe^{-2x}}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer was wrong, as others have shown and have shown you how to solve it correctly. I will show you two other methods which are way more simple (in my opinion).

1) $y=\sqrt{1+xe^{-2x}}$

$\ln(y)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+xe^{-2x})$

$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{e^{-2x}-2xe^{-2x}}{2(1+xe^{-2x})}$

$y'=\frac{e^{-2x}-2xe^{-2x}}{2\sqrt{1+xe^{-2x}}}$

2) $y^2=1+xe^{-2x}$

$2yy'=e^{-2x}-2xe^{-2x}$

$y'= \frac{e^{-2x}-2xe^{-2x}}{2\sqrt{1+xe^{-2x}}}$

You might say that method 2 is better than method 1 in this case, but method 1 can be more useful in many other cases such as when we have quotients nested into square roots.